# Custom Indexes of Null Records

Tags: largedatavolumes, custom-index

I'm reading up on Custom Indexes and the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp.meta/salesforce_large_data_volumes_bp/ldv_deployments_infrastructure_indexes.htm) says:

> By default, the index tables do not include records that are null (records with empty values). You can work with Salesforce Customer Support to create custom indexes that include null rows. Even if you already have custom indexes on your custom fields, you must explicitly enable and rebuild them to get the empty-value rows indexed.

In this context, what is a record that is null? I would've thought that a record that is null wouldn't even exist because it necessarily is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Salesforce, one index is created for each field that meets a certain criteria. Note that we're talking about database table indexes, not search indexes, which are a different topic. We'll only be talking about database table indexes here.

For each field that has an index, a database index is created. For example, Account.Name has an index, because it is a standard indexed field. If you create a custom field on Account and use External Id or Unique properties, an index will be created for that custom field. Note that any given object may have dozens of indexes on it.

As such, it is possible to have a record that is in one index, but not another. Given our example above, if Name is "salesforce.com" and External_Id__c is null, then the record will be stored in the Account.Name index, but not the Account.External_Id__c index.

Note that indexes slow down write times, but improve read times for queries that leverage it, which is why Salesforce does not index every field. This document you linked has to do with explaining the various ways that Salesforce can be tweaked for some scenarios, such as having nulls be stored in the database, or creating a custom two-column indexes.

I realize the phrasing is confusing, and this should probably be reported as a documentation feedback item so it can be updated. Just know that what they mean to say is that a record with a null value in a particular field will not be stored in a particular index that the field uses by default.

Comment: thank you! That's VERY helpful clarity. The phrasing definitely got me, we should just copy your wording and paste it in the documentation :)